# Screenshot Flash and Send

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, screenshot, flash-cs5

How do you programmatically take a screenshot of a Flash app, and send the bitmap to server? - without using javascript, just Actionscript

Comment: are you asking to take the snapshot of your main application container

Comment: http://www.quietless.com/kitchen/upload-bitmapdata-snapshot-to-server-in-as3/ is a stepbystep tutorial that integrates with the libraries mentioned below - including working source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a screenshot is as simple as drawing into a `BitmapData` object. Something like:

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData( this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight );
bmd.draw( this.stage );
```

Replace `this.stage` with whatever `DisplayObject` you want to draw. Check out the `BitmapData` docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()

Sending it to the server depends on how you're connecting to the server. If it can accept the raw data from BitmapData, then go with it. Otherwise, encode it with `JPEGEncoder` or `PNGEncoder` from the the as3corelib: https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib.

You can probably upload it through PHP, or by writing the `ByteArray` data from the image to a `URLRequest`. How that works is a bit more complicated to write here (it involves multipart/form-data). The easiest way to see how it works is to check out the Facebook AS3 API where they have image uploading working: http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/ (check out the `call()` function in the `FacebookRequest` class)

Comment: I can handle the data once it's on the PHP side - if I used the ByteArray send via URLRequest on the flash side, would it just be a binary image received on the serverside.

Comment: http://www.quietless.com/kitchen/upload-bitmapdata-snapshot-to-server-in-as3/ is the most helpful tutorial yet